# Are fullPageUrl and averageSessionDuration no longer compatible in Reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Until December 12th 2022, I was able to combine `fullPageUrl` and `averageSessionDuration` in  [run report](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport) requests to the

Following endpoint

> https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/xxxxxxxxxx:runReport

If you go [dimensions and metrics exporer](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) and select the dimension `"fullPageUrl"`, you can no longer select `"averageSessionDuration"`. They are incompatible now.

My request body in JSON looks like this:

```
    {"dimensions":[{"name":"date"},{"name":"fullPageUrl"}, 
{"name":"pageTitle"},],"metrics":[{"name":"averageSessionDuration"},{"name":"userEngagementDuration"},],"dateRanges":[{"startDate":"7daysAgo","endDate":"today"}]}
```

I get this error message as a reply:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Please remove averageSessionDuration to make the request compatible. The request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible. To learn more, see https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

I couldnt find anything in the documentation or in the changelogs.

Answer (score 0):

The Google analytics data api is in beta it is not completed which means that they are still tuning it.

Your issue is that `"fullPageUrl"` and `"averageSessionDuration"` are not longer compatible you cant use them together in a report.

That being said I cant find any mention of it in the [change log](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/changelog) so I am going to contact the team and see what they have to say.